# Partition of Space for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two hard drive space: C and D. C is lacking (small) so I saved Android studio on D. However, when I run my emulator, it says "lack of space", probably due to its saving onto C. Thus, I am wondering how to run android studio things on disk D, not C, which appears to be automatic (or any other possible fix). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Android Studio it's self. There 2 huge parts of development environment. Android SDK (can grow to few GB depends on how many components you install) and  IDE cache (more than 2 GB in my case) as described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)
Both locations can be easily changed - android sdk needs to be just moved and ANDROID_HOME environmental variable needs to be set.
Cache location is defined in [IDE's configuration](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage).